# Filter DateRange not working in PHP-Oracle DataBase

Tags: php, oracle

need to know why my date range filter in PHP not working properly. My DB is Oracle with following NLS Format:

NLS_DATE_FORMAT : DD.MM.RR

below my Filter.php:

```
`    <?php
        include 'orc_php.php';
        if(ISSET($_POST['search'])){
            $date1 = strtoupper(date("d-M-y", strtotime($_POST['date1'])));
            $date2 = strtoupper(date("d-M-y", strtotime($_POST['date2'])));
            $query=oci_parse($conn, "select distinct
       auf.aufdzhost
     , auf.aufnr
     , te.tenam
     , art.artnr
     , aup.aupmgist
from
       auf_a_v  auf
     , te_a_v   te
     , artall_v art
     , aup_a_v  aup
where
       auf.aufid            = te.aufid
       and aup.aufid        = auf.aufid
       and art.artid        = aup.artid
       and auf.aufGrpNam like 'NATCAN%'
       and aup.aupmgist    != 0
       and auf.aufdzhost BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'") or die(oci_error());
            $row=oci_num_rows($query);
            oci_execute($query);
            if($row>0){
                while($row=oci_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUFNR']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['TENAM']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ARTNR']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUPMGIST']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUFDZHOST']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
                }
            }else{
                echo'
                <tr>
                    <td colspan = "4"><center>Record Not Found</center></td>
                </tr>';
            }
        }else{
            $query=oci_parse($conn, "select distinct
       auf.aufdzhost
     , auf.aufnr
     , te.tenam
     , art.artnr
     , aup.aupmgist
from
       auf_a_v  auf
     , te_a_v   te
     , artall_v art
     , aup_a_v  aup
where
       auf.aufid            = te.aufid
       and aup.aufid        = auf.aufid
       and art.artid        = aup.artid
       and auf.aufGrpNam like 'NATCAN%'
       and aup.aupmgist    != 0") or die(oci_error());
            oci_execute($query);
            while($row=oci_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUFNR']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['TENAM']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ARTNR']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUPMGIST']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['AUFDZHOST']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>`
```

here is my index.php:

```
`
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 well">
            <h3 class="text-primary">PHP</h3>
            <hr style="border-top:1px dotted #000;"/>
            <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="">
                <label>Date:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"  name="date1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : '' ?>" />
                <label>To</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End"  name="date2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['date2']) ? $_POST['date2'] : '' ?>"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> <a href="index.php" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"><span></a>
            </form>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class="alert-info">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Project</th>
                            <th>Date Submit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php include'filter.php'?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>`
```

the result is no record found!
here is the a date record without filter: 17-FEB-23.
I'm looking for a solution since 2 day without success.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't rely on the NLS session parameters. Either use `DATE` literals or explicitly convert the string to a date.
2. Never build queries using string concatenation (that is how SQL injection vulnerabilities are introduced); instead, [use parameterised queries and bind variables.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Something like:

```php
$date1 = strtoupper(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1'])));
$date2 = strtoupper(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2'])));
$query=oci_parse(
  $conn,
  "select column_list
   from   table_names
   where  filters
   and    auf.aufdzhost BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                            AND TO_DATE(:end_date,   'YYYY-MM-DD')"
) or die(oci_error());
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":start_date", $date1);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":end_date", $date2);
$row=oci_num_rows($query);
oci_execute($query);
```

*Note: This is untested but should give you an idea how to proceed.*

Comment: Thanks Bro, I will test and let you know with outcome:)

Comment: Hi @MT0, do you have any idea why still not getting any record after filtering! I changed the codes the same way as you provided!!

Comment: @RezwanHanafi No, you need to debug it by breaking it down into discrete steps. Does `$date1` contains a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`? When you run the query directly in the database does it run? Does it provide the correct results? Etc. These are not something that we can test as we do not have your database or your PHP setup.

Comment: $date1 is connected to my index.php input filed, see above under index.php codes. the result in my sqldeveloper shows the date like "2023-02-17".